# Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin access emulated data folder

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I cannot find anyway to get access to my emulated android device's data folder.
The emulated device is the standard Nexus 5X running Oreo 8.1 (API 27).

Everything I find keeps saying just run "adb root" but when I type that into the ADB command prompt (opened from visual studio 2019) it doesnt even return anything just a new empty command prompt line.
Below is a screen shot showing the emulated device is detected. but "adb root" does nothing.

[image: adb root does nothing]

Other posts say to use the Android Device Monitor (DDMS) but clicking on the data folder in there doesn't expand and shows nothing.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but nothing I do works. Surely for development the data folder on an emulated device must be accessible ?

Whats even more frustrating about this is that I would ask this on the Xamarin forums but I can't even register because the registration page is broken and never does anything.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score -2):

Xamarin has nothing to do with the possibility of browsing your emulator files. It's a "standard" android emulator, so yes you should have a look at official Android Studio documentation like this one https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer

Comment: that doesn't provide any insight into why I cannot see anything in the data directory, or even expand it to at least see my app.

Comment: You're right it doesn't, I should have posted this as a comment, not an answer. The goal was to make you search in the right direction, and avoid any relation with Visual Studio and/or xamarin.android, because it's not related.